# Libgdx | How to render game when not in focus?

Tags: java, libgdx, desktop, scene2d

How do I render and update my game on desktop when i'm not clicked on the game window? I want it to always render, even in the background. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wyatt, in your game's main class, override pause(). If your main class implements ApplicationListener, this is done automatically. Remove super.pause() from within the override and the game will render even in the background.

Comment: The same still does not update/render in the background. Just frozen. The only that that continues is the sound, which continued before I tried what you said :\.